# Open a connection with COM1 port even if its already opened by another process in C#

Tags: c#, logging, serial-port, connection, port

Am trying to read data from the COM port in C#, I need to open the connection with the COM port first. but the port I'm trying to connect with is already opened by another process and I need other processes to be opened as well. I know the connection to the COM port is exclusive only one process can open the connection. But I wonder is it possible to read data from the same port without closing the first connection I mean Like force an opening, using Spy mode, port listening, or monitoring the port. the code I use for connection is:

```
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
                sp.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
                if (!sp.IsOpen)
                {
                    sp.Open();
                }
```

```
I get this error: **Access to the port 'COM1' is denied.**
Any help or recommendations will be grateful.
```

Answer (score 0):

No and if you will export this to a standalone application then it would probably be best to just close the other application because when you export your code, it would be meaningless to have the second application open. If you are trying to use unity with an Arduino then just close the serial monitor or the app itself.

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply. But I need the first process to stay open. I have seen spy mode just for monitoring data on some applications but I don't know how to do that in C# . The problem is that the first application uses the COM1 port and I can not close it. It is not part of my application it is completely a different software.

Comment: Are you using an arduino and the arditty unity package for the serial communications? Also what do you need to do on the second application that you need it to be open?

Comment: No am not using Arduino, am trying to read data from the medical equipment analyzer and insert the patient test result into the MySql database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to spy on a port, however you can create a sort of a hub.
I suggest that you use a process (the only one which opens the port), which will communicate with the others using sockets. If you don't know how to do that check out these :

- Sockets (Tcp listeners and clients)
- Ports
- Streams

You will use the System.Net.Socket namespace, so here's [a quick starter guide](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ajyadav123/applied-C-Sharp-net-socket-programming/) to see how it works